# github in ubuntu looking for the application?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I'm fairly new to all this programming with github and ubuntu. I'm trying to play with ruby on rails. Anyways, I've messed with windows and github, where when I install git, I can an actual application that runs, and I can open git bash. But when i just try to install github on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install git`, it seems like its already there because in the terminal command lines it says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 286 not upgraded`

But now I'm trying to search in my folders for the git application, but its not there? Am I missing something?

Terribly newbie question,

Thanks!

Comment: When you install an application, you usually don't look for it, you just type `git` in the console. If you want a GUI, you may try `gitg` or `gitk`.

Comment: @dystroy it says that the program `gitk` or `gitg` is not installed. What is the difference between the two? Thanks!

Comment: Don't hesitate to install those two small programs and test them. One is KDE based, the other one is Gnome based. As I use no gui for git, I don't remember the differences. Just try.

Comment: BTW: On linux systems you don't need a *Git Bash*. Just any terminal applications, such as `gnome-terminal`, `konsole` or `xterm` will do. The *Git Bash* is a horrible kludge specifically devised to work around Windows' limitations.

Comment: Would be nice for GitHub to make a Ubuntu version  of there desktop application. But we are still waiting. In the mean time we have the command line and a few 3rd party GUI tools.

Answer (score 4):

On Unix, you don't install "github", only git.
And it is probably already installed (in `/usr/bin`, unless you recompile it: `/usr/local/bin`)

That would allow you git repositories hosted on GitHub, from a command line session.
You also have [some GUIs for Git in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1518844/6309).

This differs from Windows where you can install:

- [Git for Windows (msysgit distribution)](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)
- And/Or [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) (which actually includes its own msysgit)

Comment: Offtopic, most distros install git under `/usr/bin` including Ubuntu. `/usr/local/bin` is used commonly for programs compiled from source by the user and installed, and any binaries not installed through the distro's package management tools. :)

Answer (score 0):

[SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) is cross-platform and runs on Ubuntu. It has perfect GitHub integration and I think it's better than the official GitHub Windows app.

Answer (score 0):

Offtopic but, there is an unofficial version of Github Desktop GUI client available for Ubuntu

To set up the package repository, run these commands:

```
 sudo wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -

 sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list'

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt install github-desktop
```

Or you can directly grab the .deb package from https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases